# No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call, Exception

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

Have a list of data need to be saved. Before the save had to delete the existing data and save the new data.
If any of the delete & save is failed that transaction need to roll back, rest of the delete & save transaction should continue.

```
public LabResResponse saveLabResult(List<LabResInvstResultDto> invstResults) {
    LabResResponse labResResponse = new LabResResponse();
    List<Long> relInvstid = new ArrayList<Long>();
    try{
    if(invstResults != null){
        List<LabResInvstResult> labResInvstResults = mapper.mapAsList(invstResults, LabResInvstResult.class);
        for(LabResInvstResult dto: labResInvstResults){
            if(dto != null){
                //delete all child records before save. 
                deleteResult(dto, relInvstid);
            }
        }
    }
    labResResponse.setRelInvstids(relInvstid);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return labResResponse;
}
```

Here new transaction will added for each delete & save

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = { Exception.class })
private void deleteResult(LabResInvstResult dto, List<Long> relInvstid) {
    try{
        labResultRepo.deleteById(dto.getId());          
        LabResInvstResult result = labResultRepo.save(dto);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

On delete it throws an exception "Caused by: **javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call"**

I can solve this by adding a @Transactional for public LabResResponse saveLabResult(List invstResults)  method. 
But my intial usecase will not work this will roll back entire list of transaction.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two problems.

The first problem is that you call the "real" `deleteResult` method of the class. When Spring sees `@Transactional` it creates a proxy object with transactional behavior. Unless you're using AspectJ it won't change the class itself but create a new one, proxy. So when you autowire this bean you will be able use proxy's method that runs transaction related logic. But in your case you're referencing to the method of the class, not proxy.

The second problem is that Spring (again if AspectJ is not used) can't proxy non-public methods.

Summary: make the `deleteResult` method public somehow and use proxied one. As a suggestion, use another component with `deleteResult` there.

Answer (score 0):

You are catching exception out of for loop, while your requirement says you want to continue the loop for other objects in list.
Put your try/catch block with-in loop. It should work fine

```
  public LabResResponse saveLabResult(List<LabResInvstResultDto> invstResults) {
LabResResponse labResResponse = new LabResResponse();
List<Long> relInvstid = new ArrayList<Long>();
try{
if(invstResults != null){
    List<LabResInvstResult> labResInvstResults = mapper.mapAsList(invstResults, LabResInvstResult.class);
    for(LabResInvstResult dto: labResInvstResults){
        if(dto != null){
            //delete all child records before save. 
               try {
            deleteResult(dto, relInvstid);
             } catch(Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
    }
}
labResResponse.setRelInvstids(relInvstid);

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return labResResponse;
```

}

Comment: I still have the same exception.

Comment: I just noticed you have put _propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW_ in transactional. It create a new transaction, and suspend the current transaction if one exists. Not sure, but this could be a reason. Can you user REQUIRED instead

Comment: In that case one fail with in the list will roll back all.

Comment: ok, just to verify have you used 
_@EnableTransactionManagement_ in your configuration file?

Comment: I'm using spring Boot @EnableTransactionManagement  is not used.

Comment: Even In case of Springboot, you need to define _@EnableTransactionManagement_ on your bootstrap Initializer class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141718/discussion-between-poorvi-nigotiya-and-rosh).